# Wordpress - Ignoring Directory via HTACCESS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I've been trying (unsuccessfully) to ignore a directory in the root of a Wordpress site. No matter what I do, it just seems to display the 404 page for these pages. The HTACCESS rules are below with my attempt to ignore /bet-reports/

## BEGIN WordPress

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(bet-reports|bet-reports/.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^doawildthing.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.doawildthing.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/wildthingfootball\.com\/" [R=302,L]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(bet-reports.*)$
RewriteRule . /someotherpage.html [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hey Phil -- I just tried this and it's still doing the same thing.

Comment: Hi Brian, I updated my answer, can you please try that.  It will now redirect /bet-reports/ to someotherpage.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<Directory "/bet-reports/">
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Hey there, Lucas. I tried this and it didn't seem to work. Where should it go?